# Закрытие соединения mysql через контекстный менеджер

Tags: mysql, python, asyncio

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что не так я делаю с контекстным менеджером.

Сделал себе контекстный хелпер поверх aiomysql для упрощения работы с бд (хочу держать все запросы в руках, без орм)

Используется так:

```
async with DbHelper() as db:
    query = 'SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE test_var1 = %s AND test_var2'
    data = test_var1, test_var2
    db.fetchone(query, data)
```

Так вот, при проверке юнит-тестами aiomysql ругается на незакрытое соединение:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py:801:
>   ResourceWarning: Unclosed connection    ResourceWarning)

При `__aexit__` я проверяю, открыто ли оно и закрываю его.

Что ещё этой шайтан-машине надо - не пойму.

Код хелпера тут:
https://github.com/Olegt0rr/DbHelper/blob/master/aiodb.py

Код юниттеста тут:
https://gist.github.com/Olegt0rr/4dbfc2f933d027d3ccad875482d954bf

Ради интереса попробовал тетировать тот же самый код без asyncio (pymysql + unittest) - предупреждений нет.

Comment: @andreymal, в коде разве не видно, что я проверяю не только курсор, но и соединение? (строка 139)

Comment: Моя невнимательность, проглядел

Comment: Хм, а вы в методе connect не прерываете цикл while после успешного подключения что ли? Или я опять что-то проглядел?)

Comment: @andreymal, вероятно в этом и есть проблема. Чуть позже попробую исправить, напишу о результатах. Спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal, да, дописал break в блок else - лишние соединения перестали создаваться! Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) нашёл ошибку в методе, инициирующем соединение.

Т.к. использовался цикл while, необходимо было прервать цикл в случае успешного создания соединения.
В блок try else была добавлена команда break. Проблема больше не воспроизводится.

Спасибо!